# Node.JS MySql Module - Cannot Connect to Any Database - ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, azure

I'm trying to use the mysql module to connect to my database. But everytime, I get the following error: `read eCONNRESET There is problem.` (Note, that last part is from my console log. See below.)

I don't think this is a problem with database security settings. I've been trying to connect to my new database (hosted on AWS) for the last several days with no luck. Then, just now I attempted to connect to an Azure database that has been running smoothly for a couple years. Same problem: `read eCONNRESET`.

By the way, if I randomly change the host string to something invalid, my code returns an error saying the host wasn't found. So that tells me it's working to some extent.

I'm very new to the coding world and need all the help I can get.

Here's my code:

```
console.log('starting Launch');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '....windows.net',
  user     : 'test',
  password : 'test',
  port     : '1433'
})

console.log('step2')

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (!err)
        console.log("conncetd");
    else
        console.log(err + "There is problem");
});
```

Comment: change port 1433 to 3306

Comment: I tried updating that in the code, but then I get an `ENOTFOUND` error -- probably because my server is set up to use port 1433. Do you recommend changing that on the server side as well? The mysql module defaults to 3306, but my understanding is that this can be easily overridden using the `port` function, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy full error message.
2. Check connectivity to your DB instance, use nmap (linux) or telnet (windows). If you can't reach host - check your local machine and server firewall, restrictions. If you can, go to 2.
3. Try to use different MySQL client, MySQL WorkBench, HeidiSQL, DBeaver.
   If you can't - than something wrong with MySQL configuration. If you can, go to 3.
4. Copy info about: OS, node version, mysql module version.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

mysql.createPool({});

instead of

mysql.createConnection({})

Comment: I've tried that once and again with no luck. Any other ideas?